Postgres Barman archive command failed
For production environment, I am using this archive command in my postgresql server.
barman-wal-archive backup pg /var/lib/edb-pge/15/data/pg_wal/%f

Now when I manually run this command on my PostgreSQL server with the exact file name it works, but when I run barman backup pg from the barman server, it throws an error in the PostgreSQL log file:
2024-07-15 07:48:33.713 PKT [20808] LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 2
2024-07-15 07:48:33.713 PKT [20808] DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: barman-wal-archive backup pg /var/lib/edb-pge/15/data/pg_wal/000000010000000000000011
2024-07-15 07:48:33.713 PKT [20808] WARNING:  archiving write-ahead log file "000000010000000000000011" failed too many times, will try again later

I dont know the issue with my archive command.

There are probably additional error messages showing exactly why the command fails.

Another line in the log says: ERROR: Error executing ssh: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
But i am not using SSH for communication with my BARMAN server. I am using postgres streaming method.

If you are using streaming, then why do you have a archive command at all?
